# how to get smartphone like scrolling for a winforms touchscreen app ( scrolling panel )

Tags: c#, vb.net, user-controls, scroll, touchscreen

After scouring the articles online I have come up with this design for a winforms based touchscreen app that needs smartphone like scrolling. The app itself will run on a tablet laptop or touchscreen desktop.

- I put everything I want to scroll on a panel.
- Set autoscroll to true (which will show scrollbars)
- Now put this whole panel inside a groupbox
- Shrink the groupbox until the scrollbars are hidden (visually hidden, not visible = false)

Now the fun part I am stuck at. I think I have to handle the mousedown, mouseup & mousemove on the panel to set the autoscrollposition so that when someone touches the panel and drags, it does it's scroll magic. Please help fill in the few lines of code in below method stubs. The [msdn doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscrollposition.aspx) on autoscrollposition is very confusing since it returns negative numbers but needs to be set to positive with abs and what not.

```
Point mouseDownPoint;
Point mouseUpPoint;
Point mouseDragPoint;
 private void myPanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
    this.mouseDownPoint = e.Location;
    Console.WriteLine("Mouse down at {0}", e.location);
 }

 private void myPanel_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
    this.mouseUpPoint = e.Location;
    this.mouseDownPoint = new Point(); //will set for IsEmpty check
    Console.WriteLine("Mouse Up at {0}", e.location);
 }

 private void myPanel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Mouse at {0}", e.location);
    if (mouseDownPoint.IsEmpty()) //finger is off the touchscreen
       return;
    myPanel.Autocrollposition = ??
 }
```

thank you

**//UPDATE - Below I have with trial and error working & tested code. (not refactored). If someone has a more elegant solution please post.**

```
    Point mouseDownPoint;
    private void innerpanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            this.mouseDownPoint = e.Location;
    }

    private void innerpanel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left)
            return;
        if ((mouseDownPoint.X == e.Location.X) && (mouseDownPoint.Y == e.Location.Y))
            return;

        Point currAutoS = innerpanel.AutoScrollPosition;
        if (mouseDownPoint.Y > e.Location.Y)
        {
            //finger slide UP
            if (currAutoS.Y != 0)
                currAutoS.Y = Math.Abs(currAutoS.Y) - 5;
        }
        else if (mouseDownPoint.Y < e.Location.Y)
        {
            //finger slide down
            currAutoS.Y = Math.Abs(currAutoS.Y) + 5;
        }
        else
        {
            currAutoS.Y = Math.Abs(currAutoS.Y);
        }

        if (mouseDownPoint.X > e.Location.X)
        {
            //finger slide left
            if (currAutoS.X != 0)
                currAutoS.X = Math.Abs(currAutoS.X) - 5;
        }
        else if (mouseDownPoint.X < e.Location.X)
        {
            //finger slide right
            currAutoS.X = Math.Abs(currAutoS.X) + 5;
        }
        else
        {
            currAutoS.X = Math.Abs(currAutoS.X);
        }
        innerpanel.AutoScrollPosition = currAutoS;
        mouseDownPoint = e.Location; //IMPORTANT

    }
```

Answer (score 10):

And as a Component:

```
public partial class TouchableFlowLayoutPanel : FlowLayoutPanel
{
    private bool _doTouchScroll;
    private Point _mouseStartPoint = Point.Empty;
    private Point _panelStartPoint = Point.Empty;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="TouchableFlowLayoutPanel" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    public TouchableFlowLayoutPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Program.mouseFilter.MouseFilterDown += mouseFilter_MouseFilterDown;
        Program.mouseFilter.MouseFilterMove += mouseFilter_MouseFilterMove;
        Program.mouseFilter.MouseFilterUp += mouseFilter_MouseFilterUp;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="TouchableFlowLayoutPanel" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="container">The container.</param>
    public TouchableFlowLayoutPanel(IContainer container)
    {
        container.Add(this);

        InitializeComponent();

        Program.mouseFilter.MouseFilterDown += mouseFilter_MouseFilterDown;
        Program.mouseFilter.MouseFilterMove += mouseFilter_MouseFilterMove;
        Program.mouseFilter.MouseFilterUp += mouseFilter_MouseFilterUp;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Handles the MouseFilterDown event of the mouseFilter control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">
    ///     The <see cref="MouseFilterEventArgs" /> instance containing the event data.
    /// </param>
    private void mouseFilter_MouseFilterDown(object sender, MouseFilterEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_doTouchScroll && e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            _mouseStartPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            _panelStartPoint = new Point(-AutoScrollPosition.X,
                                                 -AutoScrollPosition.Y);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Handles the MouseFilterMove event of the mouseFilter control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">
    ///     The <see cref="MouseFilterEventArgs" /> instance containing the event data.
    /// </param>
    private void mouseFilter_MouseFilterMove(object sender, MouseFilterEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if (!_mouseStartPoint.Equals(Point.Empty))
            {
                int dx = (e.X - _mouseStartPoint.X);
                int dy = (e.Y - _mouseStartPoint.Y);

                if (_doTouchScroll)
                {
                    AutoScrollPosition = new Point(_panelStartPoint.X - dx,
                                                   _panelStartPoint.Y - dy);
                }
                else if (Math.Abs(dx) > 10 || Math.Abs(dy) > 10)
                {
                    _doTouchScroll = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Handles the MouseFilterUp event of the mouseFilter control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">
    ///     The <see cref="MouseFilterEventArgs" /> instance containing the event data.
    /// </param>
    private void mouseFilter_MouseFilterUp(object sender, MouseFilterEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if (_doTouchScroll && !AutoScrollPosition.Equals(_panelStartPoint) &&
                !_panelStartPoint.Equals(Point.Empty))
            {
                // don't fire Click-Event
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            _doTouchScroll = false;
            _mouseStartPoint = Point.Empty;
            _panelStartPoint = Point.Empty;
        }
    }
}

internal class MouseFilter : IMessageFilter
{
    private const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
    private const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;
    private const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Filters a message before sending it
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="m">The message to be sent.This message can not be changed.</param>
    /// <returns>
    ///     true to filter the message and prevent it from being sent. false to allow the message to be sent to the next filter or control.
    /// </returns>
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        Point mousePosition = Control.MousePosition;
        var args = new MouseFilterEventArgs(MouseButtons.Left, 0, mousePosition.X, mousePosition.Y, 0);

        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
                if (MouseFilterMove != null)
                {
                    MouseFilterMove(Control.FromHandle(m.HWnd), args);
                }
                break;

            case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
                if (MouseFilterDown != null)
                {
                    MouseFilterDown(Control.FromHandle(m.HWnd), args);
                }
                break;

            case WM_LBUTTONUP:
                if (MouseFilterUp != null)
                {
                    MouseFilterUp(Control.FromHandle(m.HWnd), args);
                }
                break;
        }

        // Always allow message to continue to the next filter control
        return args.Handled;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Occurs when [mouse filter up].
    /// </summary>
    public event MouseFilterEventHandler MouseFilterUp;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Occurs when [mouse filter down].
    /// </summary>
    public event MouseFilterEventHandler MouseFilterDown;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Occurs when [mouse filter move].
    /// </summary>
    public event MouseFilterMoveEventHandler MouseFilterMove;
}

internal delegate void MouseFilterEventHandler(object sender, MouseFilterEventArgs args);

internal delegate void MouseFilterMoveEventHandler(object sender, MouseFilterEventArgs args);

internal class MouseFilterEventArgs
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MouseFilterEventArgs" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="mouseButton">The mouse button.</param>
    /// <param name="clicks">The clicks.</param>
    /// <param name="x">The x.</param>
    /// <param name="y">The y.</param>
    /// <param name="delta">The delta.</param>
    public MouseFilterEventArgs(MouseButtons mouseButton, int clicks, int x, int y, int delta)
    {
        Button = mouseButton;
        Clicks = clicks;
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Delta = delta;
        Handled = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the button.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The button.
    /// </value>
    public MouseButtons Button { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets a value indicating whether this <see cref="MouseFilterEventArgs" /> is handled.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     <c>true</c> if handled; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </value>
    public bool Handled { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the X.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The X.
    /// </value>
    public int X { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the Y.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The Y.
    /// </value>
    public int Y { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the clicks.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The clicks.
    /// </value>
    public int Clicks { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the delta.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The delta.
    /// </value>
    public int Delta { get; set; }
}

static class Program
{
    public static MouseFilter mouseFilter = new MouseFilter();

    /// <summary>
    /// Der Haupteinstiegspunkt für die Anwendung.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.AddMessageFilter(mouseFilter);
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

7 Years later but for anyone that is looking for a neat and tidy winforms solution:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

    /// <summary>
    /// Pass the panel into constructor and the control will be turned into a touch scrollable control.
    /// </summary>
    public class TouchScroll
    {
        private Point mouseDownPoint;
        private Panel parentPanel;

        /// <summary>
        /// pass in the panel you would like to be touch scrollable and it will be handled here.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="panel">The root panel you need to scroll with</param>
        public TouchScroll(Panel panel)
        {
            parentPanel = panel;
            AssignEvents(panel);
        }

        private void AssignEvents(Control control)
        {
            control.MouseDown += MouseDown;
            control.MouseMove += MouseMove;
            foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
                AssignEvents(child);
        }

        private void MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
                this.mouseDownPoint = Cursor.Position;
        }

        private void MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left)
                return;

            Point pointDifference = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - mouseDownPoint.X, Cursor.Position.Y - mouseDownPoint.Y);

            if ((mouseDownPoint.X == Cursor.Position.X) && (mouseDownPoint.Y == Cursor.Position.Y))
                return;

            Point currAutoS = parentPanel.AutoScrollPosition;
            parentPanel.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(Math.Abs(currAutoS.X) - pointDifference.X, Math.Abs(currAutoS.Y) - pointDifference.Y);
            mouseDownPoint = Cursor.Position; //IMPORTANT
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, tidy also.  but this only enable y-axis scroll, after modified this 

`Point pointDifference = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - mouseDownPoint.X, Cursor.Position.Y - mouseDownPoint.Y);` 

to enable x-axis scroll, for me I need x and y scroll, little add-on.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. If you want to move the panel when touching on the items in the panel such as PictureBox, just add MouseDown and MouseMove when creating the PictureBox and then pass that to TouchScroll.MouseDown and TouchScroll.MouseMove.

Comment: This is great, and works smooth (i am getting some extra clicks at the end of drags, but ill figure it out) BUT this is not very expandable...as in, it requires setting the mouseEvents for all children, so that any dynamically added children need the event added as they are created. It would be great to have a method that I simply inherit from to extend my class without having to customize every class I want scrolling for. (Any suggestions? is that how the Components work?)

Comment: @diox8tony I guess you could override a base control (similar to the answer from Andre) but override the add child to also add the events. However I'd make it very explicit that this is the purpose of the control... Others using that code could be very confused otherwise

Answer (score 6):

This´s my way using IMessageFilter. For everyone who´s looking for a solutiion.
First you have to implement a Filter that will listen for all Application Events:

```
internal class MouseFilter : IMessageFilter
{
    private const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
    private const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;
    private const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Filtert eine Meldung, bevor sie gesendet wird.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="m">Die zu sendende Meldung. Diese Meldung kann nicht geändert werden.</param>
    /// <returns>
    ///     true, um die Meldung zu filtern und das Senden zu verhindern. false, um das Senden der Meldung bis zum nächsten Filter oder Steuerelement zu ermöglichen.
    /// </returns>
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        Point mousePosition = Control.MousePosition;
        var args = new MouseFilterEventArgs(MouseButtons.Left, 0, mousePosition.X, mousePosition.Y, 0);

        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
                if (MouseFilterMove != null)
                {
                    MouseFilterMove(Control.FromHandle(m.HWnd), args);
                }
                break;

            case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
                if (MouseFilterDown != null)
                {
                    MouseFilterDown(Control.FromHandle(m.HWnd), args);
                }
                break;

            case WM_LBUTTONUP:
                if (MouseFilterUp != null)
                {
                    MouseFilterUp(Control.FromHandle(m.HWnd), args);
                }
                break;
        }

        // Always allow message to continue to the next filter control
        return args.Handled;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Occurs when [mouse filter up].
    /// </summary>
    public event MouseFilterEventHandler MouseFilterUp;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Occurs when [mouse filter down].
    /// </summary>
    public event MouseFilterEventHandler MouseFilterDown;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Occurs when [mouse filter move].
    /// </summary>
    public event MouseFilterMoveEventHandler MouseFilterMove;
}

internal delegate void MouseFilterEventHandler(object sender, MouseFilterEventArgs args);

internal delegate void MouseFilterMoveEventHandler(object sender, MouseFilterEventArgs args);

internal class MouseFilterEventArgs
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MouseFilterEventArgs" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="mouseButton">The mouse button.</param>
    /// <param name="clicks">The clicks.</param>
    /// <param name="x">The x.</param>
    /// <param name="y">The y.</param>
    /// <param name="delta">The delta.</param>
    public MouseFilterEventArgs(MouseButtons mouseButton, int clicks, int x, int y, int delta)
    {
        Button = mouseButton;
        Clicks = clicks;
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Delta = delta;
        Handled = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the button.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The button.
    /// </value>
    public MouseButtons Button { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets a value indicating whether this <see cref="MouseFilterEventArgs" /> is handled.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     <c>true</c> if handled; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </value>
    public bool Handled { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the X.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The X.
    /// </value>
    public int X { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the Y.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The Y.
    /// </value>
    public int Y { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the clicks.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The clicks.
    /// </value>
    public int Clicks { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the delta.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The delta.
    /// </value>
    public int Delta { get; set; }
}
```

Then you have to register this Filter to you Program:

```
static class Program
{
    public static MouseFilter mouseFilter = new MouseFilter();

    /// <summary>
    /// Der Haupteinstiegspunkt für die Anwendung.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.AddMessageFilter(mouseFilter);
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
}
```

And now you can listen for global Mouse Events and scroll your scrollable Panel like this:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private bool _doTouchScroll;
    private Point _mouseStartPoint = Point.Empty;
    private Point _yourScrollablePanelStartPoint = Point.Empty;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MainForm" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Program.mouseFilter.MouseFilterDown += mouseFilter_MouseFilterDown;
        Program.mouseFilter.MouseFilterMove += mouseFilter_MouseFilterMove;
        Program.mouseFilter.MouseFilterUp += mouseFilter_MouseFilterUp;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Handles the MouseFilterDown event of the mudmFilter control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">
    ///     The <see cref="MouseFilterEventArgs" /> instance containing the event data.
    /// </param>
    private void mouseFilter_MouseFilterDown(object sender, MouseFilterEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_doTouchScroll && e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            _mouseStartPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            _yourScrollablePanelStartPoint = new Point(-yourScrollablePanel.AutoScrollPosition.X,
                                                 -yourScrollablePanel.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Handles the MouseFilterMove event of the mudmFilter control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">
    ///     The <see cref="MouseFilterEventArgs" /> instance containing the event data.
    /// </param>
    private void mouseFilter_MouseFilterMove(object sender, MouseFilterEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if (!_mouseStartPoint.Equals(Point.Empty))
            {
                int dx = (e.X - _mouseStartPoint.X);
                int dy = (e.Y - _mouseStartPoint.Y);

                if (_doTouchScroll)
                {
                    yourScrollablePanel.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(_yourScrollablePanelStartPoint.X - dx,
                                                                 _yourScrollablePanelStartPoint.Y - dy);
                }
                else if (Math.Abs(dx) > 10 || Math.Abs(dy) > 10)
                {
                    _doTouchScroll = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Handles the MouseFilterUp event of the mudmFilter control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">
    ///     The <see cref="MouseFilterEventArgs" /> instance containing the event data.
    /// </param>
    private void mouseFilter_MouseFilterUp(object sender, MouseFilterEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if (_doTouchScroll && !yourScrollablePanel.AutoScrollPosition.Equals(_yourScrollablePanelStartPoint) &&
                !_yourScrollablePanelStartPoint.Equals(Point.Empty))
            {
                // dont fire Click-Event
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            _doTouchScroll = false;
            _mouseStartPoint = Point.Empty;
            _yourScrollablePanelStartPoint = Point.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome implementation, thank you. I'm just curious if I implemented this incorrectly. Is it expected to be able to scroll nested / multiple panels per form? If not I solved this by instead of hardcoding the container to auto scroll, on mouse down we get the bottom most scrollable control under the mouse. Than we use that for scrolling until mouse up. Of course I would like to avoid doing this if it's just a matter of misunderstanding the implementation. Thanks a lot for the share I learned a lot here.

Answer (score 4):

I used the code the OP posted but found it doesnt work if there are things with in the panel like labels. To make this work more smoothly I changed .

```
e.Location
```

to

```
PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
```

and then had all objects inside the panel also call the mousedown and mousemove events. This way not matter where you click it should move.

Answer (score 1):

To the original post, considering Cheap Funeral answer.

This version is more simple and more fluid to the touch (considers the finger move speed but not considering the effect of still scrolling after removing the finger, like moving but speeding down(maybe i'll do that whem i have time))

Works for a panel or FlowLayoutPanel

Create a form and insert a FlowLayoutPanel on it.

Form code:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Function GenerateButton(pName As String) As Button
    Dim mResult As New Button
    With mResult
        .Name = pName
        .Text = pName
        .Width = FlowPanel.Width
        .Height = 100
        .Margin = New Padding(0)
        .Padding = New Padding(0)
        .BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue
        AddHandler .MouseDown, AddressOf Button_MouseDown
        AddHandler .MouseMove, AddressOf Button_MouseMove
    End With

    Return mResult
End Function



Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    FlowPanel.Padding = New Padding(0)
    FlowPanel.Margin = New Padding(0)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 100
        FlowPanel.Controls.Add(GenerateButton("btn" & i.ToString))
    Next
End Sub

Dim myMouseDownPoint As Point
Dim myCurrAutoSMouseDown As Point
Private Sub Button_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles FlowPanel.MouseDown
    myMouseDownPoint = PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
    myCurrAutoSMouseDown = FlowPanel.AutoScrollPosition
End Sub

Private Sub Button_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles FlowPanel.MouseMove
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        Dim mLocation As Point = PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
        If myMouseDownPoint <> mLocation Then
            Dim mCurrAutoS As Point
            Dim mDeslocation As Point = myMouseDownPoint - mLocation
            mCurrAutoS.X = Math.Abs(myCurrAutoSMouseDown.X) + mDeslocation.X
            mCurrAutoS.Y = Math.Abs(myCurrAutoSMouseDown.Y) + mDeslocation.Y

            FlowPanel.AutoScrollPosition = mCurrAutoS

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

TIP:
To hide the scrolls of the flowlayoutpanel(or panel), create a usercontrol that inherits from flowlayoutpanel(or panel) and:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class FlowLayoutPanelExt
Inherits FlowLayoutPanel


<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function ShowScrollBar(hWnd As IntPtr, wBar As Integer, bShow As Boolean) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
End Function

Private Enum ScrollBarDirection
    SB_HORZ = 0
    SB_VERT = 1
    SB_CTL = 2
    SB_BOTH = 3
End Enum

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    If Me.Visible Then
        ShowScrollBar(Me.Handle, CInt(ScrollBarDirection.SB_BOTH), False)
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Me.AutoScroll = True
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Tom Hobson answer, I've modified it to auto assigning events for all child controls and its child controls

NOTE: this scroll works on Y axis only, you can see Wei Chun comment to make it work on X axis

here is the full code

```
internal class ACTouchPanel : Panel
{
    private Point mouseDownPoint;

    public ACTouchPanel()
    {
        this.MouseDown += ACTouchPanel_MouseDown;
        this.MouseMove += ACTouchPanel_MouseMove;

        this.ControlAdded += ACTouchPanel_ControlAdded;
    }

    private void ACTouchPanel_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        AssignEvents(e.Control);
    }

    private void AssignEvents(Control control)
    {
        control.MouseDown += ACTouchPanel_MouseDown;
        control.MouseMove += ACTouchPanel_MouseMove;
        foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
            AssignEvents(child);
    }

    private void ACTouchPanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            this.mouseDownPoint = Cursor.Position;
    }

    private void ACTouchPanel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left)
            return;

        Point pointDifference = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - mouseDownPoint.X, Cursor.Position.Y - mouseDownPoint.Y);

        if ((mouseDownPoint.X == Cursor.Position.X) && (mouseDownPoint.Y == Cursor.Position.Y))
            return;

        Point currAutoS = this.AutoScrollPosition;
        this.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(Math.Abs(currAutoS.X) - pointDifference.X, Math.Abs(currAutoS.Y) - pointDifference.Y);
        mouseDownPoint = Cursor.Position; //IMPORTANT
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This solution seems to be the best one out there and the most commonly accepted one - however, if you scroll to the bottom and touch a the actual flowcontrol behind the buttons (I tried to make this so that there would be empty space), you then have to double tap-and-hold the button for the scrolling to resume.  Restarting the application restores the phone-like scrolling functionality.  I am wondering if anyone else has seen this or figured it out - try it with your apps and see if it is the case as well.  I modified the snippet above so that you can start a new project, copy and paste this into form1's code, and hit run.

```
   Public Class Form1
        Dim FlowPanel As New FlowLayoutPanel
        Private Function GenerateButton(ByVal pName As String) As Button
            Dim mResult As New Button
            With mResult
                .Name = pName
                .Text = pName
                .Width = 128
                .Height = 128
                .Margin = New Padding(0)
                .Padding = New Padding(0)
                .BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue
                AddHandler .MouseDown, AddressOf Button_MouseDown
                AddHandler .MouseMove, AddressOf Button_MouseMove
            End With

            Return mResult
        End Function



        Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

            Me.Width = 806
            Me.Height = 480
            FlowPanel.Padding = New Padding(0)
            FlowPanel.Margin = New Padding(0)
            ' FlowPanel.ColumnCount = Me.Width / (128 + 6)
            FlowPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            FlowPanel.AutoScroll = True
            Me.Controls.Add(FlowPanel)
            Dim i As Integer
            For i = 1 To 98
                FlowPanel.Controls.Add(GenerateButton("btn" & i.ToString))
            Next
        End Sub

        Dim myMouseDownPoint As Point
        Dim myCurrAutoSMouseDown As Point
        Private Sub Button_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
            myMouseDownPoint = PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
            myCurrAutoSMouseDown = FlowPanel.AutoScrollPosition
        End Sub

        Private Sub Button_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
            If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
                Dim mLocation As Point = PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
                If myMouseDownPoint <> mLocation Then
                    Dim mCurrAutoS As Point
                    Dim mDeslocation As Point = myMouseDownPoint - mLocation
                    mCurrAutoS.X = Math.Abs(myCurrAutoSMouseDown.X) + mDeslocation.X
                    mCurrAutoS.Y = Math.Abs(myCurrAutoSMouseDown.Y) + mDeslocation.Y

                    FlowPanel.AutoScrollPosition = mCurrAutoS

                End If
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: Posting an answer should not ask a new question for anyone visiting the site on how to solve a code issue. If you have an issue with a code snippet, try asking a question.