# How to make touchlike scroll in winforms for a panel?

Tags: c#, winforms

As this is already asked and answered here
[how to get smartphone like scrolling for a winforms touchscreen app ( scrolling panel )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963498/how-to-get-smartphone-like-scrolling-for-a-winforms-touchscreen-app-scrolling)

i have a problem with the solution. it only works if i click on the panel directly and scroll. If i have elements like labels/textboxes all over the place it doesnt work. I would need to click in between the Elements so i touch the panel directly. So how would i now solve this? Add a Mouse Move/Down Method on ALL elements i have within the panel?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/804374/1997232).

Comment: See the IMessageFilter implementation here: [Hiding the Scrollbar while allowing scrolling with the Mouse Wheel in a FlowLayoutPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67855814/7444103). Based on the question's scope, it handles `WM_MOUSEWHEEL`, `WM_MOUSEHWHEEL` to scroll a Parent Container (Panel, FlowLayoutPanel or any other scrollable container) which is fully covered by child Controls and `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` (to know which child Control - or nested child Control - was clicked, without handling the MouseDown event of each nested Control). You can of course trap any other message.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same event for the main panel for all in-panel controls.

```
panel1.MouseDown += innerpanel_MouseDown;
panel1.MouseMove += innerpanel_MouseMove;
panel1.MouseUp += innerpanel_MouseUp;
foreach(Control ctr in panel1.Controls)
{
    ctr.MouseDown += innerpanel_MouseDown;
    ctr.MouseMove += innerpanel_MouseMove;
    ctr.MouseUp += innerpanel_MouseUp;
}
```

**Events**

```
private void innerpanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //implementation
    Control ctr = (Control)sender;
    MessageBox.Show(ctr.Name);
}
private void innerpanel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   //implementation
}
private void innerpanel_MouseUP(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  //implementation
}
```

*Just keep in mind that if you have a button in the control panel, the button click event will run and any control that has a click event.*